# Java: overriding equals method doesn't do the trick when looking for a key of hashtable?

Tags: java

I have a hashtable looking like this:

```
Hashtable<Mapping, Integer> mappingCount = new Hashtable<Mapping, Integer>();
```

I want to use this code:

```
if (mappingCount.get(currentMapping) != null)
    mappingCount.put(currentMapping, mappingCount.get(currentMapping) + 1);
else
    mappingCount.put(currentMapping, 1);
```

In order to be able to get the value from the hashtable, for the class `Mapping` I did the following:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return ((Mapping)obj).mappingXML.equals(this.mappingXML);
}
```

However, this doesn't do the trick since `mappingCount.get(currentMapping)` always results in `null`. To be sure that something's not wrong, I did the following:

```
if (aaa.contains(currentMapping.getMappingXML()))
    System.out.println("found it!");
else
    aaa.add(currentMapping.getMappingXML());
```

where `aaa` is `List<String> aaa = new ArrayList<String>()`. Of course, `found it` is printed many times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, don't use `Hashtable` - it's an obsolescent class with an outdated API. Use `HashMap` instead.

Comment: Also `equals` should not throw `ClassCastException` or `NullPointerException`.

Comment: related: [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: Remember to synchronize HashMap access if multithreaded access required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also need to override the hashCode() method.

From the [JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

> To successfully store and retrieve
>   objects from a hashtable, the objects
>   used as keys must implement the
>   hashCode method and the equals method.

The reason for this is that Hashtable uses hashCode as a preliminary test to see if two objects are equals. If the hashCode matches, then it uses equals to check for collissions.

The default implementation of hashCode() returns the memory address of the object, and for two objects that are equal, their hashcodes must also be equal.

Also look at the general contract for [hashCode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

Comment: What should I put for the hashCode? And do I have to do only for classes that I'm using in Hashtable (or HashMap), or for all of them?

Comment: Take a look at [commons-lang's HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html)

Comment: @Ivan: Eclipse (and most other modern IDEs will generate hashcodes based on your private variables.) You should do it for all objects where you override equals. All the variables that are used in your equals method should be used in your hashcode calculation.

Comment: @Gonzo: Only variables necessary for equals should be included in hashCode(). Some overly complex equals() may test fields in some branches and not others.

Comment: The idea that hashCode uses the memory address is a historical artefact http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236615/does-object-tostring-or-object-hashcode-ever-give-the-memory-address-of-the-obje

Answer (score 5):

All of the recommendations to override equals and hash code correctly are spot on; [Joshua Bloch](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf) tells you how to do it properly.

But an equally important requirement is that keys in maps must be *immutable*.  If your class can change its values, then the equals and hash code can change after you add it to the map; disaster ensues.

Comment: +1 Immutability considerations are often overlooked in oo programs.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you override `equals`, you **must** override `hashCode` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `hashCode` as well.

From the [Object#hashCode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) doc:

> Returns a hash code value for the
>   object. This method is supported for
>   the benefit of hashtables such as
>   those provided by java.util.Hashtable.
>
> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>     execution of a Java application, the
>     hashCode method must consistently
>     return the same integer, provided no
>     information used in equals comparisons
>     on the object is modified. This
>     integer need not remain consistent
>     from one execution of an application
>     to another execution of the same
>     application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
>     calling the hashCode method on each of
>     the two objects must produce the same
>     integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the
>     equals(java.lang.Object) method, then
>     calling the hashCode method on each of
>     the two objects must produce distinct
>     integer results. However, the
>     programmer should be aware that
>     producing distinct integer results for
>     unequal objects may improve the
>     performance of hashtables.
>
> As much as is reasonably practical,
>   the hashCode method defined by class
>   Object does return distinct integers
>   for distinct objects. (This is
>   typically implemented by converting
>   the internal address of the object
>   into an integer, but this
>   implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming
>   language.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement `hashcode()` as well!

Example:

```
public class Employee{
    int        employeeId;
    String     name;
    Department dept;

    // other methods would be in here 

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 1;
        hash = hash * 17 + employeeId;
        hash = hash * 31 + name.hashCode();
        hash = hash * 13 + (dept == null ? 0 : dept.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }
}
```